# Convert an image to 9 patch image loaded from server

Tags: java, android, xml, image, nine-patch

is there any way to change an image which is in jpeg format to 9 patch image by using any codes in java.The images are loaded from server.

Comment: I don't think there are any ways to convert jpeg to 9 patch

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html - looks like you need a PNG source, I recommend using `ImageIO` for converting the filetype.

Answer (score 0):

Use this library :
https://github.com/Anatolii/NinePatchChunk
convert your jpeg image to bitmap and call this method :

```
NinePatchDrawable np = create9PatchDrawable(this,bitmap,"");
```

and finally :

```
imgView.setImageDrawable(np);
```